# Cancel long running Entity Framework 6 query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 (`DbContext`) in a Winforms application, and I want to find a way to properly cancel a long running query. It's a selection query.

Actually, I generate a list of a custom object with `.ToList()`. But when the number of records is big, it needs some time to get it. I've read about cancelation token on `.ToListAsync()` and I've tried it, with no luck.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: can u share a bit of the code where the query runs for long time?

Comment: Dim result As ObjectOfMine
result = (From o As TypeOfBBDD
              Where o.field = value
              Select New ObjectOfMine With
              {
              .field1 = value1,
              .field2 = value2,
              .... several fields
              }.toList()

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to find out why your query is running so slowly. Is this just a `SELECT` query? Do you have the right table indexes? Are your queries optimal?

Comment: It's just a SELECT query, I've right table indexes.
The query it's slow only when the number of results it's big

Comment: You should provide your code regardless...

Comment: @Alfonso share the code you tired with the cancellation token. It should have done the job. Let us have a look what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry for delay.I use the following:

Comment: Sorry for delay.I use the following:
'code'
Public Async Function Function1(token As CancellationTokenSource) As List(Of ObjectOfMine)

Dim lista As New List(Of ObjectOfMine)
Using context As New UnycopWinNormEntities
       Dim source As IQueryable(Of ObjectOfMine) = definition of query
       For Each item As ObjectOfMine In Await source.ToListAsync(token.Token)
                    listaPruebaEnum.Add(item)
                Next

       return lista

End Using

Comment: And I cancel the token on GUI, this comunication works ok. The problem it's toListAsync doesn't answer

Comment: Anybody has an idea?